# How do i input doc2vec vectors combined with categorical features in a CNN to predict a class?

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, nlp, text-classification

I have a dataset with 2 features , one is a text feature and the other is a categorical feature. I want to predict the category based on these two features. I am using doc2vec to convert the text column into vectors and one hot encoding the categorical feature . After converting both the column, I don't know how to combine both of these features and feed into a neural network, say a CNN . Please guide me what approach should I take? I am new to this, please don't mind the shortcomings.

My dataset and some of the code:

[image]

Comment: What is a text feature? Do you have an idea how to model that if you didn't have the categorical feature as well?

Comment: The text feature is a column with text summaries for each row. Please see the dataset attached, you will be able to get an idea .

Comment: To me that text feature just looks like another categorical feature.

Comment: that contains sentences of texts. It is not a categorical feature.